# Adding an element in the first sentence

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="content">
  This is some title<br/>
  Some text<br/>
  And maybe more text.
</div>
```

What I want to add a `<span>` around the first sentence and before the `<br/>` like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <span>This is some title</span><br/>
  Some text<br/>
  And maybe more text.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: you can do it using JS/Jquery and regular expressions.

Comment: I know that it can be done with javascript, but how? I have minor knowledge of jQuery. Using an append or an after...? I have no clue that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Jonathan: jQuery has a wrap option for this purpose. You just have to extract the required line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.content br:first-child').each(function(){
    var t = $(this.previousSibling).wrap('<span />');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zj9Lj/).

Though if all you want to do is style the first-line, why not just use CSS's `::first-line` pseudo-element:

```
div.content::first-line {
    color: #f90;
    font-size: 2em;
    /* and so on, and so forth... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zj9Lj/1/).

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped. :)

Comment: Clever! `<br>` is a tag, therefore, can be selected using CSS type rules! much better than using a regular expression approach.

Comment: @Mark: thanks! But, to be honest, I prefer the pure CSS approach (despite the inherent IE-compatibility issues). :)